# Is there a name for set of numbers $\mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: terminology, math-history

Just out of curiosity is there a standard name for a set of numbers $\mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q}$  where $\mathbb{Q}$ stands for set of rational numbers, $i$ your complex number.

Comment: You can write $\mathbb Q(i)$ or $\mathbb Q(X^2+1)$.

Comment: People have already answered your question sufficiently well it looks like, but I'll add that if you're curious about reading more into things like this, this is related to field extensions and Galois theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called [Gaussian rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational).

This is a somewhat rare term in my experience. Yet the term [Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) for $a+ib$ with integers $a,b$ is quite common.

The former is the quotient field of the latter so the term certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

They are called [Gaussian rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational) numbers.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, there's definitely more convenient notation: the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be thought of as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ spanned by the basis vectors $1$ and $i$.  That is, $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \{x + iy \ | \ x, y \in \mathbb{Q} \} = \mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q}$.